# A way to merge adapter with data fetch from different resources

Tags: android, listview, adapter, listadapter, android-cursoradapter

I have a CursorAdapter for some data fetched from a database and another set of data fetched from a WebService , Is there a way to use one adapter (so i can set it for a single ListView) for both of them knowing that they are of the same type ?

im already using a Loader implementation to fetche from both data sources in the backgound.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a custom list adapter if both sources provide the same type.  From your loader call setList() and the adapter should do the rest.

Below is a sample skeleton implementation:

```
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


private Context          context;
private LayoutInflater   layoutInflater;
private ArrayList<T> list;

public CartListAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public void setList (ArrayList<T> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return ((list == null) ? 0 : list.size());
}

@Override
public Object getItem (int position) {
    //  In theory we should not be called if getCount() returned 0;
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId (int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    }
    if (list == null) {
        //Incase something crazy happens put something here to allow graceful failure
    }

    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView != null)
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    if (holder == null) // not the right view
        convertView = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = //your custom list view layout               


        holder = new ViewHolder();
        //Assign the different views to your holder

        convertView.setTag(holder);//Store the holder in the tag

    }
    else holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


    //Populate your views from your list

    return convertView;
}

private LayoutInflater getLayoutInflator() {
    if (layoutInflater == null) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    return layoutInflater;
}

static class ViewHolder {

         //Place your views here 
}   
}
```

From your comment it looks like you are looking for a hybrid adapter.  I have not tried to implement this before.  My first impulse would be to modify the skeleton above to have a public method that sets a boolean value to decide which data source you are using. Something like:

```
public void useCursorData(boolean cursorIsSource)
```

Then test for the data source in the overridden for example:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {//this was written in off the cuff so there might be some minor errors.
    if (cursorIsSource)
        return cursor.getCount();
    else
        return list.size();
}
```

Keep in mind that using a hybrid adapter may cause difficulty with your onClickListeners.  For example when using a cursor the position is the display index and the id is the row id.  In contrast when using an array backed adapter both the position and id reference the location in the array.

Comment: the thing is that i wanted to keep my current CursorAdapter implementation (because of some code i need to put in bindView) and somehow merge it with another adapter ?

Comment: If you want to keep your current CursorAdapter implementation you should probably store the WebService data in your database.  That way you can return either cursor to your current CursorAdapter.